# Multiple LED on arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, led, voltage-level

I am currently trying to control multiple LEDs with one Arduino Mega 2560 board. However, since each LED needs 3.6 volts and the board only supplies 5V I cannot make more than one light up.

Is there a way to increase to output voltage of the Arduino board ? Or perhaps of using arduino to turn on or off a battery that has a high enough voltage to power multiple LED ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: please explain why you think that you can only light up one LED with the Arduino.

Comment: Connect the LED in parallel, not in serie!

Answer (score 3):

Each pin on any Arduino (with some exceptions) can only handle 40mA MAX. Even the 5V and similar output sources can't handle more than 600mA, So I suggest you use them to power a MOSFET or Darlington to connect them in appropriate series and parallel connection counts.

Both the above transistors can handle high voltage, but you need to choose ones that correspond to a voltage that an Arduino can provide.

This is the most robust method if you want all the LEDs to light up at the same time. However for array addressable LEDs you might need extra BJTs coupled with resistors for each led, maybe along with two decided that would be appropriate for your application.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect them in parallel instead of series you'll be able to turn them on and off with 3.6 volts (5 volts through an appropriate dropping resistor), assuming the Arduino can supply the current. [Here's](https://www.ledsupply.com/blog/wiring-leds-correctly-series-parallel-circuits-explained/) a general explanation of the difference.

Comment: yes I had actually tried in parallel and it had not worked but today I figured out that one wire had a problem. It all works now thanks